# Como criar um serviço REST com PHP e MySQL e .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, rest, restful

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno projeto, onde algumas informações devem ser armazenadas em um banco de dados MySQL que esta hospedado em uma hospedagem com PHP, queria saber se tem jeito de desenvolver um serviço REST para inserção dos dados em um banco MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma simplificada de se fazer isso, recomendo, é através do [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/), desenvolvido em PHP, com foco na distribuição de REST APIs.

Começando ([Fonte](http://docs.slimframework.com/start/get-started/)):

1) curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

2) Crie um arquivo `composer.json` na raiz do projeto com o código abaixo:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*"
    }
}
```

3) Execute o comando `php composer.phar install`

4) Inclua no seu arquivo `index.php` o `autoloader` do framework

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Criando o "Hello World"

1) Instancie a aplicação do framework através do código:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
```

2) Crie a rota:

```
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});
```

3) Rode a aplicação:

```
$app->run();
```

Acesse seu projeto com os paths especificados no `$app->get`.
Esse é um exemplo bem básico de como funciona o Slim, para ter uma noção melhor, recomendo a leitura da [documentação](http://docs.slimframework.com/).

Comment: Obrigado Luís, vou verificar essa opção.

Answer (score 1):

A Zend, empresa responsável pelo PHP e pelo famoso Zend Framework, desenvolveu um 'gerador' de webservices chamado [ApiGility](https://apigility.org/).
Creio que seja a forma mais fácil e no Youtube há diversos vídeos sobre o assunto.

Eu particularmente gosto do Yii2. [Neste guia](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) eles mostram como é fácil criar um webservice Restful

Comment: Links podem ser bons, mas o recomendável é fornecer um exemplo, conforme sugerido em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer