# É possivel sincronizar um servidor mysql com um banco local Firebird?

Tags: mysql, aplicação-web, firebird

Sou novo em aplicações web, e tenho um site com base da SGBD MySql.

Qual é a melhor forma de sincronizar o banco web com um banco local(estando o banco em um ip fixo)? O banco local é firebird.

Comment: Recomendo que faça títulos intuitivos. Isto ajuda muito. ps: **Não fui eu** quem negativou. Acho a pergunta bem ampla, mas pode ser facilmente melhorada, basta dar detalhes do banco (note que existem estruturas do Mysql que não são compatíveis com o Firebird.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro quero que entenda que *FireBird* e *Mysql* não tem uma "tão boa" compatibilidade e provavelmente não iria conseguir importar os dados de um pro outro, cada banco e tabela que um desenvolvedor cria não tem como ter algo pronto que funcione exatamente para sua necessidade.

Não posso afirmar qual é o melhor caminho, mas vou lhe dizer sobre algo que é amplamente usado com este proposito, me refiro a compartilhar dados de um servidor com outros ambientes.

Você deve criar um webservice (de preferencia usando autenticação no servidor).

### O que é um webservice:

Webservice é uma solução utilizada na integração de sistemas e na comunicação entre aplicações diferentes. Com esta tecnologia é possível que novas aplicações possam interagir com aquelas que já existem e que sistemas desenvolvidos em plataformas diferentes sejam compatíveis. Os Webservices são componentes que permitem às aplicações enviar e receber dados. Cada aplicação pode ter a sua própria "linguagem", que é traduzida para uma linguagem universal, um formato intermediário como XML, Json, CSV, etc.

<sub>Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service</sub>

Recomendo que leia esta pergunta e respostas:

- [O que é um Web Service?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90315/3635)

### Criando um webservice

Tendo entendido o que é o REST, entenda que ele vai rodar no seu servidor web, venho a supor que o teu servidor use PHP ou ASP.NET:

- **PHP**

  Se o caso for PHP e você não tiver um conhecimento suficiente pra desenvolver a aplicação do zero ou ainda tiver necessidade de entregar rapidamente este webservice, recomendo usar um framework, segue uma lista de frameworks que suportam criar aplicação REST:

  1. [Laravel](http://laravel.com) (Suporta várias bibliotecas e autenticação)
  2. [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com) (Suporta Crypto e Session)

     Um exemplo com Slim: [Como criar um serviço REST com PHP e MySQL e .htaccess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73126/3635)
- **ASP.NET**

  Com ASP.NET você pode desenvolver rapidamente uma aplicação de REST, no ASP.NET o nome dele é *Web API* (a linguagem de programação fica a sua escolha c# ou VB.NET).

  Aprenda um pouco sobre web api aqui: http://www.asp.net/web-api

Note que estes dados passados pelo webservice não são no formato SQL e sim no formato Json ou XML, que são formatos de arquivos que você mesmo customiza.

### Lado cliente

Do lado cliente você vai ter que criar um software Desktop que acesse o webservice que você criou anteriormente e baixe os dados em seguida populando o banco Firebird. Para isto você terá que desenvolver um software somente pra acessar o webservice, baixar os dados e popular o banco local.

Pra desenvolver este software você tem a opção de usar:

- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (Por exemplo com o VisualStudio pode lhe facilitar nisto, possui versão [Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) e é muito usado, contendo uma excelente documentação)
- [java](/questions/tagged/java) (Java não cria apenas aplicativos pra Android mas também pode desenvolver aplicações Desktop)
- [pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal) delphi ou lazarus, no caso o Delphi é uma IDE muito usada no Windows que facilita o desenvolvimento Desktop, como alternativa você tem o Lazarus, que também pode ser usado no Linux.

<sub>(Me corrijam se passei alguma informação errada sobre Delphi ou Pascal, não é o meu forte)</sub>

### Conclusão

Como disse no inicio, não existe nada pronto que funcione pra cada caso especifico, você terá que desenvolver ambos ambientes, no entanto não tenha receio, este tipo de desenvolvimento é mais comum do que imagina na atualidade.